# What is the quickest way to navigate an xml document in JS?

Tags: javascript, xml, performance, optimization

I am working with a semi-large xml document (~4000 elements each with 30 sub nodes) and was wondering what the fastest way to pull the data is. Currently, my code is taking about 4 seconds to run, which isn't terrible, but it could be better.

I know with sql databases you can use **Ordinals** to get integer values to pull from the table due to string look-ups being inefficient and I was wondering if there is any way to do this with XML. Or if there is anything else I can look into / try.

My current implementation is pulling each value using `.getElementsByTagName`

```
root[i].getElementsByTagName('FirstName')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
```

Edit: *show full code*

I am pretty much just copy pasting that for all the nodes in each element. Note: there are a lot more elements, but it is the exact same implementation.

```
const AddUserData_Response = (xml) =>{
    let xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
    let root = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('User');
    let table = document.getElementsByClassName(activityTab + "-table-body")[0];
    for (let i = 0; i < root.length; i++) {
        let row = document.createElement("tr");

        CreateTableElement(row, root[i].getElementsByTagName('LastName')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
        CreateTableElement(row, root[i].getElementsByTagName('FirstName')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
        CreateTableElement(row, root[i].getElementsByTagName('MiddleInitial')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
        CreateTableElement(row, root[i].getElementsByTagName('ID')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
        CreateTableElement(row, root[i].getElementsByTagName('Title')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);

        table.insertBefore(row, table.children[0]);
    }
}
const CreateTableElement = (row, value) => {
    let cell = document.createElement("td");
    if (value != "None" && value != undefined) {
        cell.innerText = value;
    }
    row.appendChild(cell);
}
```

Comment: Can you show the full code, or at least a few examples of how you extract multiple values?

Comment: The fastest way to navigate XML typically is XPath, but very much depends on the circumstances. Is it on the client? The server? Does it first have to load the XML from somewhere?

Comment: @CertainPerformance I added the full code

Comment: Thanks, are the `LastName` etc nodes direct children of each User item in the XML?

Comment: It is impossible to tell from what little information you have given us what is causing it to take 4 seconds.  Depending on the total size of the document and the storage you are pulling it from, it could be an IO bandwidth problem  Or if you are pulling it over the network or internet it could be any of a number of network throughput issues.  Or, depending on the code you have used to initialize and then access the document, it could be a CPU/code/library issue.  For us to help you further, you would need to provide this information.

Comment: Yes, they are direct children

Comment: If there are a whole lot of users - which it sounds like there are - the problem looks pretty clear to me

Comment: @RBarryYoung [How long should we wait for a poster to clarify a question before closing?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260263)

Comment: @RBarryYoung What information would you need? I am sending an http request to get the xml document. The response is taking about 300ms. The document is being produced from an oracle database via ASP.Net C# and stored in a temp folder that can be accessed through the internet (which I am sending the request to). My cpu is an *Intel Xeon CPU E5-2603 v2 @ 1.80GHz* . For the request I am using a basic AJAX request, I can post the code for that if you would like

Comment: @VLAZ "A reasonable amount of time."  Enough time for them to respond to the requests, especially for relatively inexperienced posters.  The SE network has no problem telling new OPs to wait a reasonable amount of time for answerers to respond before selecting one as the correct answer, there's no reason that the much more experienced Closers cannot exercise the same restraint and make SO a more welcoming place for new people.

Comment: @RBarryYoung I wasn't asking. I linked you to the answers. You're welcome.

Comment: @Gunnarhawk The actual size of the transmitted data and also a description of how you are measuring the 4 seconds so that we can determine if it includes the request+response+transmission time or not.

Comment: Just so that we would nullify the request and response time. I added a `Date().getTime()` to the start and end of my `AddUserData_Response()` function. The result came out to about 2.1 seconds. The total size of the file is 4.88 MB